# Switched server & domain name, now custom post types won't save

Tags: custom-post-types, database

I had the site on oldsite.com but was using the database at newsite.com, everything was working great. I moved the site to newsite.com, now when I try adding a new post using a custom post type, it disappears, I am still able edit older posts, of the same custom post type. I checked the db when I create a new post nothing is saved, when I make changes to existing posts the change is saved.

Not sure where to look next. Thanks

this is in my functions.php
http://pastebin.com/n5baM3R8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try re-generating the permalinks structure. And check that you have the correct urls in the general options (WPURL and URL)

Comment: regenerated permalinks and urls are correct, still no luck.

Comment: perhaps it was just delayed, but it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first lines of your function for registering the post type are missing. You should get a fatal error. Check if you really took the complete file to your new site.

Comment: That was my bad, I just didn't get them when copying into pastebin. add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );     
function create_my_post_types() {